# Difference between declarative and model-based specification

Tags: terminology, specifications, alloy, z-notation

I've read definition of these 2 notions on wiki, but the difference is still not clear. Could someone give examples and some easy explanation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A declarative specification describes an operation or a function with a *constraint* that relates the output to the input. Rather than giving you a recipe for computing the output, it gives you a rule for checking that the output is correct. For example, consider a function that takes an array a and a value e, and returns the index of an element of the array matching e. A declarative specification would say exactly that:

```
    function index (a, e)
      returns i such that a[i] = e
```

In contrast, an operational specification would look like code, eg with a loop through the indices to find i. Note that declarative specifications are often non-deterministic; in this case, if e matches more than one element of e, there are several values of i that are valid (and the specification doesn't say which to return). This is a powerful feature. Also, declarative specifications are often not total: here, for example, the specification assumes that such an i exists (and in some languages you would add a precondition to make this explicit).

To support declarative specification, a language must generally provide logical operators (especially conjunction) and quantifiers.

A model-based language is one that uses standard mathematical structures (such as sets and relations) to describe the state. Alloy and Z are both model based. In contrast, algebraic languages (such as OBJ and Larch) use equations to describe state implicitly. For example, to specify an operation that inserts an element in a set, in an algebraic language you might write something like

```
    member(insert(s,e),x) = (e = x) or member(s,x)
```

which says that after you insert e into s, the element x will be a member of the set if you just inserted that element (e is equal to x) or if it was there before (x is a member of s). In contrast, in a language like Z or Alloy you'd write something like

```
    insert (s, e)
      s' = s U {e}
```

with a constraint relating the new value of the set (s') to the old value (s).

For many examples of declarative, model-based specification, see the materials on Alloy at http://alloy.mit.edu, or my book Software Abstractions. You can also see comparisons between model-based declarative languages through an example in the appendix of the book, available at the book's website http://softwareabstractions.org.

Comment: thanks for explanation! why Alloy is called declarative on the wiki? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alloy_(specification_language)